# Syntax error parsing the query

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans

after many search on web i cant find the properly solution to my case

i have a table whit several columns and i want to make a update in some off the columns

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Utilizador.updateNormal", query="UPDATE Utilizador u SET u.nome = :nome AND u.morada = :morada AND u.grupoPro = :grupoPro AND u.username = :username AND u.email = :email AND u.telemovel = :telemovel WHERE u.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Utilizador.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Utilizador u"),
```

i hant to use Utilizador.updateNormal but trow me a

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Utilizador.updateNormal: UPDATE Utilizador u SET u.nome = :nome AND u.morada = :morada AND u.grupoPro = :grupoPro AND u.username = :username AND u.email = :email AND u.telemovel = :telemovel WHERE u.id = :id], line 1, column 39: syntax error at [AND].
```

i spend many time on web to find a solution but nothing works ins my case

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `AND`. Use commas.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Utilizador.updateNormal", query="UPDATE Utilizador u SET u.nome = :nome, u.morada = :morada, u.grupoPro = :grupoPro, u.username = :username, u.email = :email, u.telemovel = :telemovel WHERE u.id = :id"),
```